# EXTJS5: Why hidden textfield is shown?

Tags: extjs4

I am having one hidden text field :
{
   xtype: 'textfield',
   name: 'myFieldName',
   id: 'myFieldId',
   hidden: true
}

for the above textfield hidden property is true even though the textfield can be seen on the extjs form... facing problem with hidden textfield only..Having other hidden fields in other forms as well, but not facing such problem in that cases.

Answer (score -1):

you can try {Boolean}true, that works for me

Comment: How does this not make sense? extjs even uses it themselves. You should check your sources.

Comment: Well, for starters it would be a syntax error. Secondly, assuming you're meaning it to be a cast, why would you cast a boolean literal? Would suggest you post a fiddle demonstrating this working using `{Boolean}true`.